# Consulta SQL con respuesta de un unico Item y valor en una columna como 'SI' o 'NO'

Tags: sql, sql-server

Necesito mostrar una consulta de un campo = Id que tiene varias columnas, entre ellas una columna llamada 'Valor' con varios valores A, B, C, D.

Si la Columna 'Valor' contiene 'C' me debe mostrar en esa columna el valor 'C' como 'SI'. Si el valor 'C' no figura me debe mostrar 'NO'. Los demás valores no deben ser mostrados. Es decir cada vez que haga la consulta me debe devolver una única cantidad con la respuesta 'SI' o 'NO' en esa columna.

Tengo puesto lo siguiente pero no me sirve ya que me sale resultado 'SI' únicamente si la columna contiene el valor 'C':

```
SELECT Columna1, Columna2 CASE WHEN  Valor = 'C' THEN 'SI' END Valor
FROM TABLA
WHERE Valor = 'C'
```

No tengo una tabla sino que seria una consulta que habría que modificar la respuesta para que apareciera como digo.

Vuelvo a añadir otro ejemplo para que quede mas claro:

Tengo esta consulta devuelta

```
ID    Columna1     Columna2     Valor
x567    JUAN         PEREZ        A
x567    JUAN         PEREZ        B
x567    JUAN         PEREZ        C
```

pero el resultado al transformarla o filtrala debe ser:

```
ID    Columna1     Columna2     Valor
x567    JUAN         PEREZ        SI
```

Si tuviera lo siguiente:

```
ID    Columna1     Columna2     Valor
x567    JUAN         PEREZ        A
x567    JUAN         PEREZ        D
x567    JUAN         PEREZ        B
```

Resultado debe ser:

```
ID    Columna1     Columna2     Valor
x567    JUAN         PEREZ        NO
```

Si añado la siguiente sentencia SQL a mi SELECT:

```
CASE WHEN Valor = 'C' THEN 'SI' ELSE 'NO' END Valor
```

Para

```
ID    Columna1     Columna2     Valor
x567    JUAN         PEREZ        A
x567    JUAN         PEREZ        B
x567    JUAN         PEREZ        C
```

me sale lo siguiente:

```
ID    Columna1     Columna2     Valor
x567    JUAN         PEREZ        NO
x567    JUAN         PEREZ        NO
x567    JUAN         PEREZ        SI
```

pero quiero que salga:

```
ID    Columna1     Columna2     Valor
x567    JUAN         PEREZ        SI
```

Para

```
ID    Columna1     Columna2     Valor
x567    JUAN         PEREZ        A
x567    JUAN         PEREZ        D
x567    JUAN         PEREZ        B
```

me sale lo siguiente:

```
ID    Columna1     Columna2     Valor
x567    JUAN         PEREZ        NO
x567    JUAN         PEREZ        NO
x567    JUAN         PEREZ        NO
```

pero quiero que salga:

```
ID    Columna1     Columna2     Valor
x567    JUAN         PEREZ        NO
```

Comment: Si la condición del where es que valor sea C ya estás eliminando los registros que tengan valor distinto de C, quita la condición

Comment: Si quito el valor C me mostrara todos los valores que no son 'C' y yo solo quiero que me muestre un valor. Voy a ver si pongo mejor el ejemplo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo primero es obtener los datos de Id, Columna1 y Columna2:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Id, Columna1, Columna2
FROM Tabla
```

Ahora a esa consulta, se le debe agregar la columna `Valor`, para lo cual puedes usar un `CASE` de esta forma:

```
SELECT CASE
           WHEN COUNT(*) > 0 THEN 'SI'
           ELSE 'NO'
       END
FROM Tabla
WHERE Valor = 'C' AND ...
```

[Documentación del comando `CASE`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) (en inglés).

Por último solo queda juntar ambas consultas:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Id, Columna1, Columna2,
   (    SELECT CASE
                   WHEN COUNT(*) > 0 THEN 'SI'
                   ELSE 'NO'
               END
        FROM Tabla T2
        WHERE Valor = 'C'
          AND T2.Id = T1.Id
          AND T2.Columna1 = T1.Columna1
          AND T2.Columna2 = T1.Columna2
   ) AS Valor
FROM Tabla T1
```

Comment: Necesito que si en la columna tiene un valor concreto por ejemplo 'C' me lo sustituya por 'SI'. Para los demás valores me debe mostrar 'NO' y además solo me debe mostrar una fila. En mi caso como tengo además de C, los valores A, B y D me muestra mas de una fila

Comment: No acabo de entenderlo, también me debe mostrar las columnas, columna1, columna2 y columna Valor ( Valor tendrá un SI o No )

Comment: Podrías agregar un ejemplo de los datos que tienes y el resultado que esperas para esos datos...

Comment: Ok, voy a volver a editar la pregunta con mas ejemplos

Comment: Según planteaste la pregunta, @Popularfan, entendí que ésta era una solución óptima para el resultado esperado. Si esperas más datos (que la consulta traiga el valor de otras columnas) debes decirlo con claridad.

Comment: @A.Cedano he vuelto a añadir mas ejemplos a ver si así se entiende mejor.

Comment: @Popularfan ahora se entiende mejor, pero faltan detalles todavía. Por ejemplo, ¿sólo te interesan los datos de `JUAN PÉREZ` (teniendo entonces que agregar un filtro `WHERE` para filtrar por el nombre o por el id según los datos de que se disponga) o interesan los datos para cada fila de la tabla agrupada por cada persona individual? Sea como sea, es muy evidente que tu tabla necesita ser normalizada, hay demasiada redundancia de datos.

Comment: No es una tabla, es el resultado de otra consulta que se debe tratar agregando otras sentencias SQL para que aparezca el resultado como explico.

Comment: @MarcosCrispino la Tabla no es una tabla es el resultado de otra consulta. Tendría que añadir tu código  al resultado de un select.

Comment: Ok, pude adaptar esta solución y me funciona !! Gracias

Answer (score 1):

No sé si es lo más eficiente pero puedes probar:

```
SELECT distinct ID , Columna1, Columna2, 'SI'
FROM TABLA
WHERE valor = 'C'
UNION
SELECT distinct ID , Columna1, Columna2, 'NO'
FROM TABLA
WHERE valor <> 'C' and ID not in (SELECT ID FROM TABLA WHERE valor = 'C')
```

Comment: Pero esto se lo tengo que agregar al resultado de la consulta que tengo, porque lo que explico es el resultado de otra consulta.

Comment: Yo lo he planteado como sustitución de la consulta que has puesto. No sé si te sigo ¿Quieres decir entonces que realemente no existe la tabla TABLA?

Comment: Tabla es el resultado de una consulta y a esa consulta es la que hay que transformar.

Answer (score 1):

La solución más eficiente sería usando MAX(). Esto permite que la tabla se lea sólo una vez.

```
CREATE TABLE TABLA(
    ID      char(4),
    Columna1 varchar(10),
    Columna2 varchar(10),
    Valor char(1)
)
INSERT INTO TABLA(
ID, Columna1, Columna2, Valor)
VALUES
('x567','JUAN', 'PEREZ', 'A'),
('x567','JUAN', 'PEREZ', 'B'),
('x567','JUAN', 'PEREZ', 'C'),
('x568','PANCHO', 'LOPEZ', 'A'),
('x568','PANCHO', 'LOPEZ', 'B'),
('x568','PANCHO', 'LOPEZ', 'D');

SELECT Columna1, Columna2, MAX(CASE WHEN  Valor = 'C' THEN 'SI' ELSE 'NO' END) Valor
FROM TABLA
GROUP BY Columna1, Columna2;

GO
--Descomentar la linea para limpiar lo que se hizo. Cuidado de no eliminar tablas reales.
--DROP TABLE TABLA
```

Comment: De esa manera me tira un error, no tendría que poner MAX() AS Valor?

Comment: `AS` es opcional. Sería bueno saber cual es el error que arroja.

Comment: No me funciona , si pongo el MAX no me lo acepta me sale un error en la consulta si solo dejo el CASE WHEN Valor... etc.. END Valor, si que me hace una consulta pero el resultado no es el esperado.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error? Acabo de probar el código y funciona perfecto. El problema puede ser al trasladar el código. Sin saber que dice el error es imposible ayudar.

Comment: No puedo trasladar todo el código porque es un select muy largo con varias tablas que me da un resultado y ese resultado es el que quiero luego filtrar con otro select para que me de la salida que yo quiero. Creo que tengo que montarlo como una subconsulta. Es decir el resultado de mi select tienes que verlo como una tabla en memoria donde luego hay que hacerle otro select.

Comment: Repito, sin saber cual es el error, no puedo saber como corregirlo. El código publicado funciona sin problemas.

Comment: Ok, pude adaptar  la solución de Marcos alfinal me funciona de esa manera. Gracias por tu ayuda igualmente.

Comment: Pon una advertencia sobre esto: **`DROP TABLE TABLA`**, si el OP lo copia tal cual se va a cargar toda su tabla. Entiendo que lo usaste de prueba, pero deberías poner un comentario de advertencia muy visible en el código.

Comment: Lo haré, aunque si alguien tiene una tabla llamada TABLA, los problemas son más grandes, comenzando por las filas insertadas.